# load image as prop in react-native

Tags: javascript, image, react-native

so I have a customHeader component where I am trying to load images into like so

`<Image source={props.logoImg} style={styles.icon} />`

and on the page I'll pass in the prop like so

```
<CustomHeader 
     navigation={props.navigation} //call props.navigation in component
     primaryColor={primaryColor}
     coName={coName}
     logoImg={require('../content/...some image...'}
 />
```

This way it doesn't throw an error, but it doesn't load. I know it has something to do with passing it as a prop because I can load images straight into the screens. I'm just not sure what I'm doing wrong or what I'm missing here.

I have tried using the require inside of the component, but that throws an error at compile because react-native needs the images to be "required" at compile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this should work

in the Wrapping component

```
<CustomHeader 

     imageUri={'../content/...some image...'}
 />
```

and then in the inner component

```
<Image source={require(props.imageUri)} />
```

Comment: that throws a javascript build error

`components\CustomHeader.js: components\CustomHeader.js:Invalid call at line 15: require(props.imageUri)`

Comment: so it also seems that just using images in components doesn't work? I'm trying `<Image source={require(...some img...)} />` straight into the component and it doesn't throw any errors, but it doesn't load. the same line works if I use it on the page though.

Comment: for me  its work https://snack.expo.io/@yoel301/icon-in-child

Comment: Just found out that react-native images requires a height style. I kinda feel dumb, but also I feel it shouldn't need that.